# Undefined watchHeading in compass plugin for ionic/phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, compass-geolocation

Well, I'm working on a small project made in ionic. I'm using ngCordova to add some cool plugins, like device orientation for compass. But I can't force it to work. I already installed ngCordova and added plugins (geolocation plugin works). I'm out of ideas why this doesn't work.

Code looks like this:

```
.controller('GeoLocationCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaGeolocation, $cordovaDeviceOrientation, $ionicPlatform, $document) {
$scope.lat = 0;
$scope.long = 0;
$scope.position = {};


$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
var options = {frequency: 1000}; // Update every 1 second
var watch2 = $cordovaDeviceOrientation.watchHeading(options); ///LINE 53!

watch2.promise.then(function (result) { /* unused */
    },
    function (err) {
        // An error occurred
    }, function (position) {
        // Heading comes back in
        // position.magneticHeading
        $scope.position = position.magneticHeading;
    });

    $cordovaDeviceOrientation.clearWatch(watch2.watchId)
        .then(function (result) {
            // Success!
        }, function (err) {
            // An error occurred
        });

  });
})
```

But all I get is this:

```
ripple.js:37
TypeError: Cannot read property 'watchHeading' of undefined
    at Object.watchHeading (http://localhost:8080/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-        cordova.min.js:1:14565)
    at http://localhost:8080/js/controllers.js:53:44
    at http://localhost:8080/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:37388:19
    at Object.ionic.Platform.ready     (http://localhost:8080/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:1915:9)
    at Object.self.ready (http://localhost:8080/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:37386:26)
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/controllers.js:15:20)
    at invoke (http://localhost:8080/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11591:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8080/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11602:23)
    at http://localhost:8080/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:14906:28
    at updateView (http://localhost:8080/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:42986:30) ionic.bundle.js:17696
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you add the plugin to your project? i.e. `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device-orientation`

Comment: Sorry, I guess I messed description... But, yes, I added this plugin in that way. It's in sources of projects, it's added, so I guess it's installed properly.

Comment: Well, also when I'm adding console.log on cordovaDeviceOrientation.watchHeading(options) it returns object. So I'm almost sure that plugin is installed fine